# How can I go across the columns coping non empty cells into another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some simple VBA, I just want it to go across all of the columns in my spreadsheet and if there is a value then copy it across to Sheet2 making one long list there.

I am going wrong somewhere, and I was hoping that it's simple enough that someone would be able to let me know where I'm going wrong.

```
Dim c As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim w As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim p As Integer
' Define w as the width of the dataset
w = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(100000, 1).End(xlUp).Column
' Run this for each column 
For c = 1 To w
' Define l as the length of the column
l = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 100000).End(xlUp).Row
' Run this for each cell in the column
    For r = 1 To l
' If there is something in the cell, copy it across to Sheet 2 Column 1
        If Cells(l, w).Value <> "" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, p) = Cells(l, w).Value
            p = p + 1
        End If
    Next r
Next c

End Sub
```

A solution would be great, but knowing where I'm going wrong would be better - I really want to understand what's the issue here.

Cheers,

Tom

Comment: exactly HOW is this not working?

Comment: `"I really want to understand what's the issue here."` - So do we.  Can you perhaps *describe* the problem?

Comment: `Cells(l, w).Value` >> `Cells(r, c).Value`

Comment: Anytime you post a question, it is idea for you to include any error message that is occurring and the line that is highlighted when it occurs. If you aren't getting an error message then describe the expected behavior and then the actual behavior.

Comment: Run-time error '1004'

Application-defined or object defined error

When I debug it highlights

    l = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 100000).End(xlUp).Row

as the line.

Sorry, I apologise for not providing this originally

Answer (score 1):

If I got your problem there are some bad assumptions in your code

But first let's see if that's what your actually looking for:

```
Sub main()
    Dim p As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cell as Range 

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set rng = .Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        With .Worksheets("Sheet2")
            For Each cell In rng
                p = p  + 1
                .Cells(1, p) = cell.Value
            Next cell
        End With 

    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks far better than what I wrote (I feel ashamed).

This is returning 1 for every cell in the range (ie if 20 cells value is not blank, then it returns 20 1s - I'm looking for it to return the actual cells contents.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote "rng" where there was to be "cell". See edited answer

Comment: Thanks!! That's amazing.